# Why can't I hear anybody on Google Hangouts, or Meet when I use Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, mute, google-hangouts

I cannot hear anyone on Hangouts, Google Meet, or web.skype.com calls when I use Chrome as my browser.  This is happening on both Linux and Macos. When I use Firefox or other browsers, I am able to hear perfectly.

Comment: Please post your solution as an actual answer. You might want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the HTML5 Autoplay Chrome Extension was preventing me from hearing the audio.  To resolve it I can either
disable or remove the extension.  Alternatively you can set the 'Mode Rules List' in the extension's
'Details | Extension Options' like this:

```
hangouts.google.com nothing
```

See disable-html5-autoplay Modes and Mode Rules for details: [Modes and Mode Rules](https://github.com/Eloston/disable-html5-autoplay/wiki/Modes%20and%20Mode%20Rules)